# fixed header/footer, liquid content with margin

Tags: css

I have made a design with a fixed header and footer, with a liquid middle.

I have the middle in a margin, but the trouble is the scrollbar is not margined.

Here is what I have made:
http://jsfiddle.net/xXxV4/

As you can see, the scrollbar is tight to the header, footer and right side. I want it to have the content div with the 20px margin

Comment: Isn't "liquidness" about *not* having `px` stuff?

Comment: i dunno - regardless, it is the look i'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 20px 0px 20px 0px; /* NEW */
}
```

So, the scrollbar gets a 20px margin as well.

Comment: almost, yeah - the trouble is it doesn't have the margin on the right, it seems to ignore it even if you put one in

Comment: thank you - in combination with Jared's contribution I have got what I needed

Comment: yeah, you can't put a right margin und this ui-element, so with jared's solution this should work nice. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `#main` element is `position: absolute`, so you could `right: 20px`?

```
#content{
    padding: 20px 0 0 20px;
    overflow: auto;
}

#main{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    overflow: auto;
    bottom: 40px;
    right: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/xXxV4/5/

Comment: If you want a margin on the right side as well (thought only on top and bottom) this is the only solution.

Comment: It works in FF13, IE7-9, Operat 11.67 and Chrome. I don't have Safari.

Comment: @user887515 - Also, I included the `padding` part because you have to compensate for the `right: 20px` to pull it back to the right inside.